# Can I submit an App to the Apple App Store with multiple targets?

Tags: swift, swiftui, storyboard, app-store

Objective:

I created a macOS application. I have users that still use macOS 10.15 however I wanted to use SwiftUI. macOS 10.15 SwiftUI is very different from the newer version for this I created 2 targets.

Target 1:

1. I created a target and selected storyboard as interface. I deleted the storyboard then I edited the info.plist.
2. I created a group (folder) in the project root called "shared" and then created a swiftUI view.
3. I edit the AppDelegate.swft to show the SwiftUI View

This all works as expected

Target 2:

1. I created this target and selected SwiftUI as the interface.
2. I then when to demoProject_App and change the view from ContentView to the View in the shared group (folder). I also added that SwiftUI view as a membership for this target. and This Target works as expected.

My Question:

I need to submit the app to the App Store. Can I submit the full project as one application so that when a users goes to download it they can only download for the target their system allows or do I have to submit them as different apps?

Comment: You'd have to submit it as different apps

Comment: Can the apps have the same name. I take it as this might not be a good idea as one may get rejected and one could be approved (when I want to add features)

Comment: No, they cannot have identical names

Comment: A better approach is not to have different versions of the app, but to support legacy versions with the availability check (`if #available`). So you have the same base, and isolate components that are version-specific. Where it comes to using them you do version check